# How to inject more complex service in slim3 such as Paytrail

Tags: php, dependency-injection, slim, slim-3

Below is an example code for "Paytrail_Module_Rest.php", a set of classes for interacting with a rest api for a payment gateway. Some of the classes can be instantiated ahead of time such as (Paytrail_Module_rest which holds credentials), but some need to be instantiated with information only available in the controller, (such as Paytrail_Module_Rest_Payment_S1 which sets payment details such as price)

Can anyone suggest a clean way of injecting it into slim3? I can't see any good way of doing it with the standard container injection methods.

```
$urlset = new\App\Service\Paytrail\Paytrail_Module_Rest_Urlset(
    "https://www.demoshop.com/sv/success", // return address for successful payment
    "https://www.demoshop.com/sv/failure", // return address for failed payment
    "https://www.demoshop.com/sv/notify",  // address for payment confirmation from Paytrail server
    ""  // pending url not in use
);

$orderNumber = '1';
$price = 99.00;
$payment = new \App\Service\Paytrail\Paytrail_Module_Rest_Payment_S1($orderNumber, $urlset, $price);

$payment->setLocale('en_US');

$module = new \App\Service\Paytrail\Paytrail_Module_Rest(13466, '6pKF4jkv97zmqBJ3ZL8gUw5DfT2NMQ');

try {
    $result = $module->processPayment($payment);
}
catch (\App\Service\Paytrail\Paytrail_Exception $e) {
    die('Error in creating payment to Paytrail service:'. $e->getMessage());
}

echo $result->getUrl();
```

( credentials listed here are public test credentials )

Comment: Slim supports any PSR-7 HTTP message implementation. You could write a Middleware for that and consume the Attributes in the action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the stuff that doesn't change to the container like the module and the urlset thingy

```
$container[\App\Service\Paytrail\Paytrail_Module_Rest_Urlset::class] = function($c) {
    return new \App\Service\Paytrail\Paytrail_Module_Rest_Urlset(
        "https://www.demoshop.com/sv/success", // return address for successful payment
        "https://www.demoshop.com/sv/failure", // return address for failed payment
        "https://www.demoshop.com/sv/notify",  // address for payment confirmation from Paytrail server
        ""  // pending url not in use
    );
};

$container[\App\Service\Paytrail\Paytrail_Module_Rest::class] = function($c) {
    return new \App\Service\Paytrail\Paytrail_Module_Rest(13466, '6pKF4jkv97zmqBJ3ZL8gUw5DfT2NMQ');
};
```

And then you either can instantiate the payment every time you need or add a helper class like an adapter:

```
class PaymentAdapter {

    public function __construct(
            \App\Service\Paytrail\Paytrail_Module_Rest $module,
            \App\Service\Paytrail\Paytrail_Module_Rest_Urlset $urlset) 
    {
        $this->module = $module;
        $this->urlset = $urlset;
    }

    function createAndProcessPayment($orderNumber, $price) 
    {
        $payment = new \App\Service\Paytrail\Paytrail_Module_Rest_Payment_S1($orderNumber, $this->urlset, $price);

        $payment->setLocale('en_US');
        try {
            $result = $module->processPayment($payment);
        }
        catch (\App\Service\Paytrail\Paytrail_Exception $e) {
            die('Error in creating payment to Paytrail service:'. $e->getMessage());
        }
        return $result;
    }

}
```

Then add the adapter also to the container:

```
$container[\yournamespace\PaymentAdapter::class] = function($c) {
    return new \yournamespace\PaymentAdapter(
        $c[\App\Service\Paytrail\Paytrail_Module_Rest::class],
        $c[\App\Service\Paytrail\Paytrail_Module_Rest_Urlset::class]
    );
};
```